# c# string format

Tags: c#, string

How do I get the output of this to read 0 instead of 00 when the value is 0?

```
String.Format("{0:0,0}", myDouble);
```

Comment: Did you really mean a thousands-separator (`,`) or do you want a decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0:#,0}", myDouble);
```

*(tested version)*

Comment: This will an empty string for 0.

Comment: Well, it took me some time before I fired up Visual Studio, but now I *did* test it.

Comment: I find Mono's [C# REPL](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) comes in handy for quick testing like this.

Comment: @Matthew - Well, if I'd go that way, I'd might as well use a text file and the command prompt, as Jon Skeet says he does :) But otherwise it seems as an interesting app, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:#,0}", myDouble);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. To my defense, I can say that I first checked in Visual Studio, and then when I came back to correct my answer I saw Matthew had posted his, but hmm, who would believe me...

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use this:

```
string s = string.Format("{0:n0}", myDouble);
```

If you always want commas as the thousands separator and not to use the user's locale then use this instead:

```
string s = myDouble.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the posted answers here `("{0:#,0}")` are correct I would strongly suggest using a more readable picture (also to avoid confusion about decimal/thousand separators):

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0}", v);     // to print 1,234
string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", v);  // to print 1,234.56
```

But all those pictures work the same, including 2 comma's for 1e6 etc.